# Nginx redirect URL with specific query parameter on url

Tags: nginx

Nginx, I am trying to redirect one url matching the query parameter but it doesn't work.

```
http://www.example.org/xyz?abc=123&color="<K>" to the below URL http://www.example.org/anything/something).
```

I tried below but it didn't work.

```
location = /xyz {
    if ($args ~* "^&color="<K>") {
        rewrite ^.*$ /anything/something redirect;
    }
}
```

Anyone can help on it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The characters such as `"`, `<`, and `>` are [URL encoded](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding) in the original request and remain encoded in the `$args` variable.

Also, the `^&` in your regular expression, anchors the `&` to the beginning of the query string, whereas there is actually another parameter in front of it.

The following example appears to work correctly:

```
location = /xyz {
    if ($args ~* "&color=%22%3CK%3E%22") {
        ...
    }
}
```

---

Alternatively, you can test the value of the `color` parameter directly using:

```
location = /xyz {
    if ($arg_color = '%22%3CK%3E%22') {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried for below also but didnt help out with below.

http://www.example.org/xyz?abc=123&color=K  to http://www.example.org/anything/something

location = /xyz {
    if ($args ~* "&color=K") {
        rewrite ^.*$ /anything/something redirect;
    }
}